Manga/anime in which the main character fights demons that want to invade and protects those that want peace
There is this manga/anime that begins with some dudes digging a huge pot which they open, releasing a demon.
The demon kills them and runs off, then it's hit by a delivery girl and the demon possesses her. The main character (MC) is an exorcist and had previously transformed into a busty girl so as to rent a house, which it turns out was haunted by a demon that was previously hunted by other demons to extinction.
Anyway, the girl kinda controls the possession and the MC takes her with him.
